# Concurrency with shell scripts in failure-prone environments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, concurrency

Good morning all,

I am trying to implement concurrency in a very specific environment, and keep getting stuck. Maybe you can help me.

this is the situation:

-I have N nodes that can read/write in a shared folder.

-I want to execute an application in one of them. this can be anything, like a shell script, an installed code, or whatever.

-To do so, I have to send the same command to all of them. The first one should start the execution, and the rest should see that somebody else is running the desired application and exit.

-The execution of the application can be killed at any time. This is important because does not allow  relying on any cleaning step after the execution.

-if the application gets killed, the user may want to execute it again. He would then send the very same command.

My current approach is to create a shell script that wraps the command to be executed. This could also be implemented in C. Not python or other languages, to avoid library dependencies.

```
#!/bin/sh
# (folder structure simplified for legibility)
mutex(){
  lockdir=".lock"
  firstTask=1 #false

  if mkdir "$lockdir"  &> /dev/null
  then
    controlFile="controlFile"

    #if this is the first node, start coordinator
    if [ ! -f $controlFile ]; then
      firstTask=0 #true
      #tell the rest of nodes that I am in control
      echo "some info" > $controlFile
     fi

     # remove control File when script finishes
     trap 'rm $controlFile' EXIT
  fi
  return $firstTask
}


#The basic idea is that a task executes the desire command, stated as arguments to this script. The rest do nothing
if  ! mutex ;
then
  exit 0
fi

#I am the first node and the only one reaching this, so I execute whatever
$@
```

If there are no failures, this wrapper works great.  The problem is that, if the script is killed before the execution, the trap is not executed and the control file is not removed. Then, when we execute the wrapper again to restart the task, it won't work as every node will think that somebody else is running the application.

A possible solution would be to remove the control script just before the "$@" call, but that it would lead to some race condition.

Any suggestion or idea?

Thanks for your help.

**edit**: edited with correct solution as future reference

Comment: How do you send the command to the nodes - is it purely the presence of the script? Do the nodes sit there watching the shared directory - if so, how? Have you thought of using a pub/sub mechanism with RabbitMQ or zeromq or Redis?

Comment: I am using Slurm workload manager. It implements a client-server hierarchy.  It seems to be similar to RabbitMQ for this purpose. Also, I am looking for solutions that do not oblige to modify the software stack, and that's why I look for bash or C implementations. 

Besides that, I considered the creation of a robust concurrency system on bash/C  with this particular specifications as a challenge to myself (and maybe to some others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trap syntax looks wrong: According to POSIX, it should be:

```
trap [action condition ...]
```

e.g.:

```
trap 'rm $controlFile' HUP INT TERM
trap 'rm $controlFile' 1 2 15
```

Note that `$controlFile` will not be expanded until the trap is executed if you use single quotes.

Comment: you were absolutely right.  I thought hat the behaviour of trap was like "kill", detecting some signals by default. Anyway, "trap 'rm $controlFile' EXIT" has the desired behaviour.